# Single Exchange 2007 server - two AD domains

Tags: exchange, domain

CURRENT:

single domain, single Exchange 2007

NEW:

two domains, single Exchange 2007

Can this be done?

Details:

Current setup is a single W2k3 domain with a single Exchange 2007 server.  We are merging with another company that currently hosts their email with their ISP via POP3.  We'd like to start hosting their email on our Exchange server using their existing domain SMTP addresses.  They don't have an AD domain at all at the moment.

Recommendations?  Can I do this with a trust between the 2 domains?

Requirements:

- They can't have multiple SMTP addresses on both domains...such as I've seen with articles pointing to "hosting multiple domains".  I want companyA to have the same account settings they've always had...companyB to have the same SMTP address they've had and not an additional one on the current companyA Exchange domain.
- They should be able to collaborate (calendar, contacts, GALs) but should still be distinguishable based on which company they "work for".

Please help...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you state...

> NEW:
>
> two domains, single Exchange 2007

Are you referring to two AD domains, or two email domains?

If you simply want two email domains, then this is definitely possible.

If you want all users to have email addresses on both domains, you could use an [address policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124401.aspx), if you want to give specific users email addresses on specific domains, then you need to [configure them individuall](http://www.petri.co.il/configure-specific-email-addresses-exchange-2007-recipients.htm)y.

Comment: two AD domains AND two email domains is what I'm after...in a single forest if possible.

Comment: This article (and articles linked from it), talks about planning deployments such as yours. Whilst it doesn't cover your scenario exactly, it should provide you with the information you need.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998636.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you are after linked users see:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123524.aspx